# Telegram bot files upload using Telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I want to upload a videos to a telegram bot from API when requsted. To do so i used sendVideo method that recieve chat_id and media.source this approch is sending the file to the chat bot and then giving the file_id in the result, which can used to send the video much faster.
I want only to store the file_id in my DB and send the vid by its file_id when it requested.
There is a way to upload the file and get thier file_id without actually sending them to the chat ?

i have tried using all sending media methods of telegraf, all of then sending the file and only then retrieve the file_id.